# Using React and Vue in same application

Tags: node.js, react

I am new to node js and react as well as Vue. 
A new project has come up and we are instructed to use node js with postgreSql and react.

The lead developer investigated and found the ramp up period / learning curve will be less  if we use vue instead of react.

so it was agreed that vue would be used to get the original system out, and we will later phase in react to replace vue.

Is it possible to create some screens using vue and some screens using react in the same application? Was thinking since there is a learning curve either way we could split focus use both technologies and later have less items to replace.

Just not finding much reading on using both, most sites want to put them up against each other in React vs Vue type of setup.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

At the moment the reason for this seemingly backwards way of doing this is a subsidiary to a bigger company needs an application out ASAP to manage their day to day workings, the powers that be (not me) thinks the fastest way to do this is node js, Vue with postgresql... 
The "Main" company is moving towards React so we will in future want to move this application in that direction as well to be more in line, but for now not being forced to

Comment: "`so it was agreed that vue would be used to get the original system out, and we will later phase in react to replace vue`" - so, you are going to code it twice?

Comment: Ideally no! The hope is one of two things... 
1) 3 quarters of the dev team can go ahead with the application in Vue and start fledgling out the most important features first to get the MVP up and running while the other devs work on less important items but using React in same application. 

2) everybody uses vue get the application up and running and then slowly replace some of the vue components with React until everything is now using React. 

I am just not sure if either of these approaches are possible with out a re-code, thus the question.

Comment: Put an AnglurJs guys onto Vue. they will find it familiar

Answer (score 1):

that not a problem at all.

React is a library.
Vue is a framework.

So using react inside of Vue is absolutely no problem. 
Using vue inside of react is harder but there are already some projects out where focussing on it (github).

If you want to simply have some components in react and some in vue its neither a problem. Since both can work independently. At the moment many projects moving from react to vue. So if you look at their migration-tutorials you can get an idea how you can let them communicate with each other.

Comment: Thank you for your response, will start looking into migration tutorials, will leave this open for now to see what other suggestions I get, if not I will mark this as answer. 
thanks